# Running RandomizedSearchCV for tuning LightGBM Regressor for large data

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cpu-usage, grid-search, lightgbm

I'm working on training a LightGBM regression model for a dataset of about 3 million points with 22 features. I'm trying to tune the model hyperparameters using RandomizedSearchCV.It takes a very long time. I'm using a virtual machine on Google cloud, with 24 CPU cores and 32G ram.

When I try to use all CPU cores for the random search or most of them like below:

```
# Use the random grid to search for best hyperparameters
# First create the base model to tune
lgbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor()
# Random search of parameters, using 2 fold cross validation, 
# search across 100 different combinations, and use all available cores
lgbm_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = lgbm, param_distributions = random_grid, 
                         n_iter = 100, cv = 2, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error',
                          verbose=10, random_state=42, n_jobs = 18)
```

It stops with this error:

> A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated.  This could be caused by a segmentation fault while
>   calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the
>   Operating System to kill the worker. The exit codes of the workers are
>   {SIGKILL(-9)}

How can I use all CPU cores to do this normally?

Is it making a difference to run the random search on GPU instead of CPU? and how many cores of GPU is suitable to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should remove `n_jobs` from `RandomizedSearchCV` and it will solve the problem. You can specify the `num_threads` in LightGBM hyper-parameters to use parallel Learning (*which is an `alias` of `n_jobs` in LGB*).

[As per the official guide](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html), use all the threads of your machine is not recommended. You should use something less than your CPU cores threads.

> for parallel learning, do not use all CPU cores because this will
>   cause poor performance for the network communication